# Python 3 - HTML Parser - Make dictionary from the data

Tags: python, html-parsing

How can I get a dictionary of the data from tags like these:

```
<Currency_name>U.S. dollar</Currency_name>
<Observation_ISO4217>USD</Observation_ISO4217>
<Observation_date>2015-03-09</Observation_date>
<Observation_data>1.2598</Observation_data>
<Observation_data_reciprocal>0.7938</Observation_data_reciprocal>
```

for example I want a dictionary like `{U.D. dollar: [USD, 2015-03-09, 1.2598,0.7938]}`

I am using

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    self.dic = {}
    if tag == 'currency_name':
        self.dic[currency_name] = handle_data()`

def handle_data: 
    return data
```

Comment: so not to consider `tagname` ? only data ?

Comment: Well I'm having troubles with getting the data from handle_data in general. How do you deal with handle_data in general? It just gives me all data each line at a time, without being able to control when calling it. Like if i wanna call it for a certain tag name, how do I do that?

Comment: Then why  you need `html parser` for `xml` parsing ?

Comment: It's what were learning in class

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use [XML PARSER](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) here an example

```
a='''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank>4</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
<country name="Panama">
    <rank>68</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
</country>
</data>'''

 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 root=ET.fromstring(a)
 #to parse from file use ET.parse('country_data.xml')

 b={}
 for child in root:
    b.update({child[0].text:[child[i].text for i in range(1,len(child)-2)]})
    b[child[0].text].extend(value for neighbor in child.iter('neighbor') for k,value in neighbor.items())
```

**OUTPUT**

> > > b=
> > >       {'4': ['2011', 'N', 'Malaysia'], '68': ['2011', '13600', 'W', 'Costa Rica', 'E', 'Colombia'], '1': ['2008', '141100', 'E', 'Austria', 'W', 'Switzerland']}

Comment: Thats not what I wanna do.

Comment: you should had mentioned before in your question that you don't want to use XML Parser. we are not any code writing service

Comment: yeah before i could have given a complete answer OP stop me with the comment "Thats not what I wanna do" and someone gave me downvote so i felt its better to leave off.I'll just update my answer with an example

Comment: Keep this in mind: an answer whose sole content is a link (as is this one) is *never* a good answer. You should always provide a *complete* answer in the body of the answer itself, and provide any additional links. But the body of the answer without the hyperlinks should already be a working answer. That's why you received a downvote. Learn, and avoid the next time.